# How to rename a field in all documents of a collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with thoses documents :

```
{
  _id: int32, 
  payment_ids: [bindata], 
}
```

and I want to rename payment_ids to id_payments in all it's documents :

```
{
  _id: int32, 
  id_payments: [bindata], 
}
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it correctly, You can `$rename`

```
db.next.update({},{$rename:{"id_payments":"payments_ids"}})
```

Replacing `next` with the actual collection name.

---

Other considerations

> If the document already has a field with the `<newName>`, the $rename operator removes that field and renames the specified `<field>` to `<newName>`

From [mongodb $rename docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)